# Passing control values to partial view rendered in a popup with Asp.net MVC3

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, jquery

I have created a popup to load a partial view. I want to pass control values from the parent page to the partial view rendered in the popup. How can I pass the values?

Below is the the code used to open the popup. `ModifyAgRule` is the div id and `AuthorityGridModify` is the name of action method used to render the partial view.

Some more info:

I have a webgrid in the parent page, when the user selects one row in this grid and clicks on the modify button a popup should appear with the selected values present in dropdowns and textboxes.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //define config object
        var dialogOpts = {
            title: "Modify Rule",
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 500,
            width: 500,
            open: function () {
                //display correct dialog content
                $("#ModifyAgRule").load("AuthorityGridModify");
            }
        };
        $("#ModifyAgRule").dialog(dialogOpts);    //end dialog

        $('#Modify').click(function () {
            $("#ModifyAgRule").dialog("open");
            return false;
        });    
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You're passing the name of your partial view to the `load()` function, which won't work as this should be passed a URL to load content from, and has no knowledge of content within your MVC project. Could you please post the content of the partial view containing the popup, and detail what values you're looking to pass accross.

Comment: Hi rory, I am not passing the name of the partial view in load I have passed the name of the action method to render the partial view and this code is working for me , the only problem is I dont know how to pass the values from the parent screen to the action method which is returning the partial view. Thanks

Comment: Sorry - my bad, misread your OP.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass data to your view in JSon format like this

```
$("#ModifyAgRule").load('@Url.Action("AuthorityGridModify")', 
                               { 'propertyName' : 'propertyValue', 
                                 'propertyName2' : 123 });
```

in your controller

```
public ActionResult AuthorityGridModify(string propertyName, int propertyName2)
{
    // propertyName´s value is propertyValue
    return View();
}
```

**hope this helps!**

Comment: How would I be able to recieve this data in the action method , will it be recieved as string in the parameter to the action method? should my action method look like this   Function AuthorityGridModify(byval controlValues as String) with the controlValues and controlValues  will hold values passed from jquery?

Comment: My answer shows how you receive the data. The type depends on the data you send. In my sample it is a string, but it can be int, arrays and more.

Comment: You can pass values of multiple controls separately and not in just one variable.

Comment: @Ismail i know, i updated my answer to make this more clear. thank you

Comment: @dknaack I knew that you know it, I was saying that to OP.